# Why newest sbt runs my app in the background?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have an akka http app. Recently I've upgraded it to sbt 1.6.1(it works ok on 1.5.4) and experienced weird issue.

Usually when I started my app it "locked" the sbt - I wasn't able to do anything, I just saw logs.

Now it looks like app is running in the background - I see logs, but also I see sbt prompt and I can use other commands.

I want to go back to the way it was before. How can I do it?(without reverting sbt version)

Comment: Sounds surprising, is the SBT version the only change you made? If you have a reproduction case, it may be worth opening an issue at SBT or Akka team 

Answer (score 1):

It is an [open issue](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/6767) at a sbt repository. It comes form changes made in 1.5 -> 1.6.

The simplest workaround (from the discussion) is to add the following line to the `build.sbt`:

```
Compile / run / fork := true
```

This way, `run` command runs in separate thread, while `test`s remain unaffected. (It is not recommended to add simply `fork := true`, as it adds overhead to every test case).

There is, however, a side effect when using SJ4F loggers: at the beginning of the run, it shows some errors (to indicate that some logs has been intercepted at initialization). To solve it, simply add a statement:

```
Compile / run / outputStrategy := Some(StdoutOutput)
```

- see more information on forking in [sbt docs](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Forking.html)
- changing the default option of fork setting has been [discussed](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/6413) extensively in sbt repo